# Web map attribute selections?

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, arcgis-web-appbuilder

With every web map I have seen or created (my creation experience is limited to the ArcGIS.com ecosystem) the user interacts with the web map by clicking on a map feature.  For example, clicking on a lake will pop up information such as its depth, area, and water quality.

What I *haven't* seen is a web map where the user interacts with it via an attribute table selection, such as "show all lakes larger than 1 hectare and deeper than 100 meters".

I've perused the ArcGIS.com web mapping applications without finding an example that provides the ability to make attribute selections.

Did I miss one?

I'm not a programmer, so I am restricted to creating web maps via "canned" or "template" options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Esri's ArcGIS Web AppBuilder. You can build apps in Portal or ArcGIS Online with the functionality you described (using the attribute table and query widget). There are many more widgets you will likely find interesting as well.

Comment: Web AppBuilder looks like it will be a good solution.  For anyone reading this in the future, I was unaware of Web AppBuilder because I did not have the requisite paid ESRI subscription.  Subscription info is available at https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/arcgis-online/buy

Comment: Experience builder is effectively the lastest low code app building solution from esri, you may want to look at that too. It's built on the ArcGIS Javascript api v4 while WAB is v3. So there is some new functionality there. Although not all WAB widgets are available in Experience Builder yet. Instant apps (in ArcGIS Online) or Configurable Apps (the equilvalent for ArcGIS Portal) are also good solutions for creating quick apps.